# Cant Access netbeans nexus maven repository, connection reset

Tags: maven, netbeans, repository, netbeans-platform

I'm building a Netbeans platform maven application but it seams that the [repository](http://bits.netbeans.org/nexus/content/groups/netbeans) that hosts Netbeans modules is down or something.

```
    <repository>
            <id>netbeans</id>
            <name>NetBeans</name>
            <url>http://bits.netbeans.org/nexus/content/groups/netbeans/</url>
        </repository>
```

I'm getting this error when I try to build the project.

```
Apr 04, 2016 10:22:37 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
Apr 04, 2016 10:22:37 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
```

as for today 20/04/2016 it shows this error

> An error occurred.
>
> Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable. Please
>   try again later.
>
> If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should
>   check the error log for details.
>
> Faithfully yours, nginx.

Comment: http://bits.netbeans.org/nexus is currently back up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm it has been down for the past few days as well.  However, I've been using http://repo.spring.io/libs-release-remote/ as it has the `netbeans-platform` artifacts that I need.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't have the required artifacts for releases greater than `RELEASE80`

Answer (score 1):

I confirm it's not working for me either (2016-04-20). It was working yesterday (2016-04-19).

Nginx replies with an error:

> An error occurred.
>
> Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable. Please
>   try again later.
>
> If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should
>   check the error log for details.
>
> Faithfully yours, nginx.

Comment: I'm going to make a local proxy for this repository once it comes back online, it's the best way do deal with this.